# Changing the button colour after making a booking

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm having an issue when trying to change the colour of a button when referencing the button as a string? I want to change the colour when a booking has been made in my program and because I am reading from a file (in is a buffered reader) I was thinking about passing in the button name as a string

Is there any way to do this?

```
while (in.hasNext()){
        seat = in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();
        seatNum = "btn" + seat;

        seatNum.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 0));

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? what happens when you run the code?

Comment: I submitted the code that worked there but have changed it now to the code that is throwing an error. 'seatNum.setBackground();' is the issue. I cannot reference a button using a String.

Comment: what is the error? show the stacktrace

Comment: cannot find symbol
symbol: method setBackground(Color)

Comment: **Please show the stack trace**. what does netbeans show you when the error is thrown?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.lang.String.setBackground

Comment: i want to pass in a string variable as a button name is that possible?

Comment: There is a way, but it's very, **very** complicated. I'll try to explain in my answer

Comment: ok that would be good, thanks

Comment: still working on it

Comment: I got it! Uploading answer now

Comment: updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use these two functions:

```
public static void loadButtonAndUpdateColor(String filename) {
        BufferedReader br;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filename)));
            String[] color = br.readLine().split(",");
            int[] vals = new int[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < color.length; i++) {
                vals[i] = Integer.parseInt(color[i]);
            }
            Color c = new Color(vals[0],vals[1],vals[2]);
            btnNewButton.setBackground(c);
            repaint();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == btnNewButton) {
            FileWriter fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileWriter(new File("path to file"));
                Color c = new Color(251,51,0);
                fos.write("" + c.getRed() + "," + c.getGreen() + "," + c.getBlue());
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            loadButtonAndUpdateColor("path to file");
        }
    }
```

The first one is static, and can be placed wherever you want.
The second one needs to be in your JFrame class. I named the button `btnNewButton`...

Comment: @gw95 if the answer worked, mark it as accepted (V symbol under answer score). Also, if you think an answer is good, upvote it...